# Selecting rows using multiple LIKE conditions from a table field

Tags: sql, sql-like

I created a table out of a CSV file which is produced by an external software.
Amongst the other fields, this table contains one field called "CustomID". 
Each row on this table must be linked to a customer using the content of that field.
Every customer may have one or more set of customIDs at their own discretion, as long as each sequence starts with the same prefix.
So for example: 
Customer 1 may use "cust1_n" and "cstm01_n" (where n is a number)
Customer 2 may use "customer2_n"

```
ImportedRows
  PKID CustomID        Description
  ---- --------------- --------------------------
  1    cust1_001       Something
  2    cust1_002       ...
  3    cstm01_000001   ...
  4    customer2_00001 ...
  5    cstm01_000232   ...
  ..
```

Now I have created 2 support tables as follows:

```
Customers
  PKID Name
  ---- --------------------
  1    Customer 1
  2    Customer 2
```

and

```
CustomIDs
  PKID FKCustomerID SearchPattern
  ---- ------------ -------------
  1    1            cust1_*
  2    1            cstm01_*
  3    2            customer2_*
```

What I need to achieve is the retrieval of all rows for a given customer using all the LIKE conditions found on the CustomIDs tables for that customer.
I have failed miserably so far.
Any clues, please?
Thanks in advance.
Silver.

Comment: You should always name your dbms when asking SQL questions here, because the different dbms (and even versions) differ in what functions are available.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Not to mention that even basic SQL commands or data types sometimes have different meanings or limitations for certain edge cases. Also consider providing a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), Silver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use LIKE you must replace the * with % in the pattern. Different dbms use different functions for string manipulation. Let's assume there is a REPLACE function available:

```
SELECT ir.* 
FROM ImportedRows ir
JOIN CustomIDs c ON ir.CustomID LIKE REPLACE(c.SearchPattern, '*', '%')
WHERE c.FKCustomerID  = 1;
```

Comment: How stupid I am... I didn't realize I could use LIKE as a JOIN condition... Thank you mate! It obviously works...